# QuickSynergy Auto-Start on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I'm pretty new to the Ubuntu world, I've used it as at a workplace before but never personally on my home computer, but I felt it was time for a change. I run Windows 8 on my laptop and Ubuntu 12.10 along-side my Windows 8 on my Desktop using Synergy on Windows I use my mouse and keyboard from my laptop (as the server) on my Ubuntu Desktop (as a client). The only problem I am encountering is having the script auto-start. I either need an option to have it started before login or after, but preferably before.

Again note that I am a very new user to Ubuntu and do not know much besides >sudo apt-get (haha). I'm hoping somebody in the Ubuntu family would become me by helping me out with this problem.

Thanks,

Brandin Arsenault
Founding President
Operation Unfriend Bullying

Answer (score 0):

If you do have an GUI installed, simply search in the dash for "Startup Applications".

This tool will allow you to add startup applications.

just write "quicksynergy" in the name and command fields, then reboot your PC to see if its working.

Comment: This will open the QuickSynergy application but does not start the service as a client. Are you aware of a way to script this to automatically start in client mode?